# Is it possible to use jQuery to determine line height?

Tags: php, jquery, css

The best way to explain this is using an example:

```
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;overflow:hidden;">
   <?php echo $content; ?>
</div>
```

How can I use jQuery to see if there's text overflowing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare the element's `scrollHeight` (DOM property, hence `.get(0)`) and `height` to check whether the contents of an element exceeds the element's boundaries or not.

```
var $div = $("div"); //Assume one div. Use a more specific selector
var isOverflowing = $div.get(0).scrollHeight != $div.height();
//The variable `isOverflowing` is true if the text overflows
```